# C# and ADB installing apk file to the connected device with WFA

Tags: c#, android, adb

im trying to make C# WFA Device Manager. Such as device list, reboot recovery, installing apk file.

So my problem starts here device list, reboot recovery works with no problem but when i try to install apk file its stuck on "Performing Streamed Install" then nothing comes. For better explain
My code

```
private void execProc(string deviceID,string cmdArg)
    {
        
            string cmd = "\\tools\\adb.exe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + cmd + " " + cmdArg;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();
       
        string res = "";
        while (!process.HasExited)
        {
            res += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = res;

               
    }
```

This is how i call the func

```
private void agentInstallBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string deviceID = richTextBox3.Text;
        execProc(deviceID, "install -r" + Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + "\\blabla\\blabla.apk");
    }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQrbX.png)

Comment: So you are trying to install an APK file via adb while the phone is in recovery mode? What recovery ROM do you use? Most recoveries only support `adb sideload` command. `adb install ...` therefore should be used while the phone is booted into regular OS.

Comment: no problem with the install process, i can do with myself writing on the cmd but im trying to make this happen on c#

Comment: adb.exe can directly be executed, you don't need to wrap it in `cmd /c ..` call. Better to keep your code "simple and stupid".